# get website name from packet using Jnetpcap

Tags: java, packet-sniffers, jnetpcap

I've asked this to Jnetpcap forum. And didn't get any response.
I've been trying to get the website name from the request/ response packet.
This is what I've tried:

```
PcapPacketHandler<String> jpacketHandler = new PcapPacketHandler<String>() {  
    final Tcp tcp = new Tcp();  
    final Http http = new Http();  
    final Ip4 ip = new Ip4();

    public void nextPacket(PcapPacket packet, String user) {
        if (packet.hasHeader(http)) {    
            packet.getHeader(http);  
            final String content_length =     http.fieldValue(Response.Content_Length);  
            final String response_code = http.fieldValue(Response.ResponseCode);  
            //Find if the given packet is a Request/Response Pkt : First get the TCP header   
            packet.getHeader(tcp);  
            Integer int_tcp_source = new Integer(tcp.source());  
            Integer int_tcp_destination = new Integer(tcp.destination());  
            if(int_tcp_source!=80 && content_length==null){  
                //It is a Request pkt :   
                packet.getHeader(http);  
                final String ref = http.fieldValue(Request.Referer);  
                final String req_url = http.fieldValue(Request.RequestUrl);  
                String page_url = http.fieldValue(Request.Host);   
                System.out.printf("\n Referer  " +ref +req_url );//Get the URL  
                System.out.printf("\nHost " +page_url);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

But it doesn't even go inside the :

```
if (packet.hasHeader(http)) {
```

**I'm using windows laptop and wireless connection.**

if I try:

```
if (packet.hasHeader(ip)) {//Ip4
```

I can get into the *if block* and can retrieve the source and destination IP address.

I basically need to do the same thing as http://jnetpcap.com/?q=node/937.

I'm really stuck and really need someone's help.

**Or simply can someone please help me to figure out how to get the website name from the packet?
some code snippet would be great.**

Can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: facing a similar issue. Were you able to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
PcapPacketHandler<String> handler = new PcapPacketHandler<String>() {
    // Protocol handlers
    private final Tcp tcp = new Tcp();
    private final Http http = new Http();

    @Override
    public void nextPacket(PcapPacket packet, String userString) {
        if (!packet.hasHeader(tcp)) {
            return; // not a TCP package, skip
        }
        if (!packet.hasHeader(http)) {
            return; // not a HTTP package, skip
        }
        if (http.isResponse()) {
            return; // not a HTTP request, skip
        }

        System.out.println("Referer: " + http.fieldValue(Request.Referer));
        System.out.println("Request URL: " + http.fieldValue(Request.RequestUrl));
        System.out.println("Host: " + http.fieldValue(Request.Host));
    }
}
```

If I run this for http://www.stackoverflow.com, I get the following output:

```
Referer: https://www.google.com/
Request URL: /
Host: stackoverflow.com
Referer: http://stackoverflow.com/
Request URL: /Js/stub.en.js?v=eb1d547a9670
Host: cdn.sstatic.net
Referer: http://stackoverflow.com/
Request URL: /Sites/stackoverflow/all.css?v=4e41902aa7a6
Host: cdn.sstatic.net
...
```

Are you sure you are not trying to access a HTTPS resource? In that case, the call to `packet.hasHeader(http)` will fail.